# Classification of certain algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a complex algebraic curve. It is well known that if $L$ is a special divisor on $C$, i.e., $h^0(L) > 0$ and $h^1(L) > 0$, then
$$
h^0 (L) \le \frac{1}{2} \deg L + 1.
$$
Assume that $L$ is not trivial and $L \ne K_C$. The equality holds if and only if $C$ is hyperelliptic.

My question is that: if there is a nontrivial special divisor $L$ on $C$ such that $L \ne K_C$
$$
h^0 (L) = \frac{1}{2} \deg L
$$
holds, then what conditions $C$ should satisfy? For example, $C$ could be hyperelliptic. Is there a complete classification?

Comment: This questions seems unclear at the moment. First of all, every curve has a special line bundle satisfying the equality $h^0(L) = \frac{1}{2}deg(L)+1$; namely the canonical bundle. Hyperelliptic curves are unique because they also possess a line bundle which satisfies the equality which is neither the trivial bundle nor the canonical bundle. So, is your question asking which curves possess some special line bundle satisfying $h^0(L) = \frac{1}{2}deg(L)$? Or, are you asking for a list of all line bundles on all curves which satisfy the equality, akin to Clifford's theorem?

Comment: One more comment: If you are simply looking for curves which possess a line bundle satisfying the equality, then any curve possessing a $g^1_4$ obviously works. This includes all hyperelliptic curves, but also all curves of genus at most $6$. More generally, you might try checking when the Brill-Noether number associated to $d=deg(L)$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}deg(L)-1$ is non-negative. I haven't done the calculation, but it seems that using this strategy you might find that every curve possesses a line bundle satisfying your equality?

Comment: Right. I should assume that $L$ is not canonical bundle. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris book? I don't have it with me right now, but is the first place I'd look.

Answer (score 11):

Notice first of all that if $|L|$ has a fixed part, then applying Clifford's theorem to the moving part of $|L|$ one obtains immediately that the fixed part is a point, $C$ is hyperelliptic and $|L|$ is a multiple of the $g^1_2$. 
So we can assume that $|L|$ is free.
Another remark is that $K_C-L$ also satisfies $h^0(K_C-L)=\deg(K_C-L)/2$, so we can also assume $\deg L\le g(C)-1$.

There exists a more precise form of Clifford's theorem, sometimes called "Clifford+" that can be useful for answering your question. The statement is the following (cf. [Beauville, "L'application canonique pour les surfaces de type g\'en\eral", Invent. Math. 55, 121-140, (1979], Lemma 5.1):

> Let $C$ be a smooth curve and $L$ a divisor of $C$ with $\deg L\le g(C)-1$. Then one of the following holds:
>
> (i) $h^0(L)\le \deg  L/3+4$;
>
> (ii) there exists a a degree 2 map $f\colon C\to \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma$ is a smooth curve and the moving part of $|L|$ is equal to $f^*|\Delta|$ where $\Delta$ is a divisor of $\Gamma$. In this case $h^0(L)\le \deg L/2+1-g(\Gamma)$.

In your case you get immediately that for $h^0(L)\ge 13$ the map given by $|L|$ factors through a double cover $C\to \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is either rational or elliptic. If $\Gamma$ is rational, then $C$ is hyperelliptic and $L$ is multiple of the $g^1_2$, but this is not possible since we are assuming that $2h^0(L)=\deg L$. So $C$ is bielliptic and $|L|$ is pulled back from an elliptic curve.

The cases with $r:=h^0(L)-1\le 11$ I think should be done by hand. For $r=1$ any tetragonal curve will do, as pointed out in the comments. For $r>1$,  the image $C'$ of $C$ via $|L|$ has degree $\ge r$, hence if $r>2$ then the map given by $|L|$ has degree $\le 2$. If the degree is 2 then $C'$ has degree $r+1$ hence $C'$ is elliptic (it cannot be rational, otherwise the system $|L|$ would not be complete) and we are in the previous situation. If the map given by $|L|$ is birational, then you can use Castelnuovo's bound to give an upper bound for $g(C)$ in terms of $r$. In case $r=2$ there's one more possibility: $C'$ is a conic and $|L|$ gives a map of degree 3. This corresponds to the case in which $C$ is a trigonal curve and $L$ is twice a $g^1_3$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume $L$ is base point free.  I think it is clear how to change what I have written in the case where there are base points (numbers goes down by the degree of the base locus).  In general, if $L$ is a line bundle of degree $d$ and $h^0(C,L)= r+1$, then the Clifford index of $L$, written Cliff(L) $= d-2r$.  Cliffords theorem is Cliff(L) >= 0.  Your line bundle satisfies Cliff(L) = 2. Two ways to achieve that if for the curve $C$ to have a $g^1_4$ or be a plane sextic. The Clifford index of a curve is the min{cliff(L)| $h^0(L)$ & $h^1(L)$ >=2}.  For a general curve $C$, Cliff(C) is the floor of (g-1)/2.  So for a general curve this can't be done. It is absolutely true that A-C-G-H will have more details and I believe a careful perusal will give the classification of all curves with Clifford Index  2. I think it is only the cases I mention.